# Show 0 and 1 are the only elements satisfying the identity $a^2=a$ for an integral domain. Give a ring that has three elements that satisfy $a^2=a$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

Let $R$ be an integral domain. Show that $0$ and $1$ are the only elements satisfying the identity $a^2=a$. Give an example of a ring and at least three elements in that ring that satisfy $a^2 = a$.

For the first part, how would I go about proving this?

For the second part, aren't the elements $[0]_6,[1]_6,[3]_6\in \Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ an example of elements from the ring $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ that satisfy $a^2 = a$ because $[0^2]_6=[0]_6$ ,$[1^2]_6=[1]_6$, and $[3^2]_6=[9]_6=[3]_6$?

Comment: The second part is good. For the first part, how would you show a = 0 or a = 1 in, say, elementary algebra? The same proof works here, precisely because the ring is an integral domain.

Comment: @quasi That might not be a really good hint, because one possible answer is "divide by $a$ if it's not zero", and you can't generally divide in an integral domain.

Comment: @David You can cancel multiplication by non-zero elements, though. Which is basically saying that "dividing $x$ by $a$" makes sense if $a$ goes into $x$. For the integers, for instance, you can divide $12$ by $3$, but not by $5$. In this case, if $a$ is non-zero, you can divide both $a$ and $a^2$ by $a$.

Comment: Well, in _elementary_ algebra, students are generally advised _not_ to divide by a nonconstant algebraic epxression, since without more care, a root may be lost. Instead, they're taught to leave the common factor as is, get everything on one side, then factor.

Comment: @Arthur Cancellation is fundamentally different from division, though of course they are related.  I have to say that what you have suggested sounds to me like a recipe for confusion among beginning students.

Comment: @David It works fine for elementary schoolers with integers, so it should be ok, at least informally. But yes, I do agree that technically, division is connected to multiplicative inverses, which are not guaranteed to exist in integral domains, while cancellation is something else.

Comment: @Arthur Yes it should work **informally** - that's exactly my point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: $a^2 = a \implies a(a-1)=0$

Comment: Oh my gosh. I feel so silly. I figured it would have been much more complicated. So because R is an integral domain, by definition, it does not have zero divisors which means a=0 or a-1=0 which means a=0 or a=1. Is that it or do I need to show anything else. I always feel like I'm missing something when an answer is so short. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @eulersnumber yes that's it.